# Powershell Hyper-V remote execution receives no response

Tags: powershell, scripting, remote-server, hyper-v

I have a work machine(A) and a different Hyper-V server (B) with virtual machines running.

If I connect to the Hyper-V server B with RDP and run `Get-VM Where-Object {$_.State -eq 'Running'}` I get a valid answer:

```
Name          State   CPUUsage(%) MemoryAssigned(M) Uptime     Status
----          -----   ----------- ----------------- ------     ------
vm1           Running 2           2048              20:07:05   Operating normally
vm2           Running 0           1024              3.00:49:30 Operating normally
```

Next, I wrote a PS script to run on my work machine A:

```
$sess = New-PSSession $SETTING_SESSION_HOST
$commandStr = "Get-VM | Where-Object { `$_.State -eq 'Running' }"
#or a simple version: $commandStr = "Get-VM"
[console]::writeline("Executing: [{0}]", $commandStr)

$commandBlock = [scriptblock]::Create($commandStr)
$job = Invoke-Command -Session $sess -ScriptBlock $commandBlock -AsJob
Wait-Job $job
$vml = Receive-Job $job

foreach($m in $vml)
{
    [console]::writeline("Executing: [{0}]", $m.Name)
}

$g = Format-List -InputObject $vml
[console]::writeline("format list: [{0}]", $g)
```

Here I would expect to see 2 lines containing "vm1" and "vm2" respectively. But I get an empty response:

```
Executing: [Get-VM | Where-Object { $_.State -eq 'Running' }]
format list: []
```

Any idea on how to get remote response from remote job?
Also, the execution time of the script is ~6 seconds (all spent in Wait-Job), while on the server it runs instantaneously.

EDIT: added -AsJob parameter
EDIT: fixed variables

Comment: Does it help when you add `-AsJob` to the end of `Invoke-Command -Session $sess -ScriptBlock $commandBlock`?  By default `Invoke-Command` doesn't return a job object.  An alternative is to get rid of the job idea as it isn't helping you - simply let `$job` fill up with the results of the command, then work with that.

Comment: The result is actually when running with -AsJob, this was lost in post editing

Comment: I dont understand the alternative ... I need to wait on the job somehow

Comment: `Invoke-Command` is synchronous by default (i.e it blocks further execution until it's done).  You are making it async by using `-AsJob`, then making that synchronous by immediately waiting on it.  I don't see the need for the job object.  If you call `$job = Invoke-Command -Session $sess -ScriptBlock $commandBlock`, PowerShell will wait at this point anyway until all the data is returned and added to `$job`, then you can deal with it later in the script.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you don't use the built in -computername of get-vm? Like: Get-VM -ComputerName ServerB | Where-Object { $_.State -eq 'Running' }

Comment: Hyper-V is not installed on machine a since it's disabled by company IT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some debugging, I found the answer: when there's only 1 machine running, then the return result is an object of type `Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.VirtualMachine`, so this code works nicely:

```
$vml = Invoke-Command -Session $sess -ScriptBlock {Get-VM | where State -eq 'Running'}
$vml.Name
```

However, if there are more than 1 machine running, then the result is `Object[]`, and the code I found out working is like this:

```
$vml = Invoke-Command -Session $sess -ScriptBlock {Get-VM | where State -eq 'Running'}
$len = $vml.length
if ($len)
{
    [console]::writeline("Machine count: [{0}]", $len)
    for ($i=0; $i -lt $len; $i++)
    {
        $m = $vml[$i]
        [console]::writeline("machine: [{0}]", $m.Name)
    }
}
else
{
    [console]::writeline("Machine: [{0}]", $vml.Name)
}
```

Note that doing a `foreach($m in $vml)` doesn't seem to work for some reason.

The problem in my opinion is that the method is either returning an object or an array.

Comment: i am currious: what version are you running? what does `$psversiontable` return? for me it does not matter whether it returns one or two vms; foreach should always work.

Comment: on work machine (A), I have PSVersion 5.1.15063.1209, build version 10.0.xxx. On the remote Hyper-V server, I have PSVersion 4.0, BuildVersion 6.3.xxx

Answer (score 0):

may I suggest the following:

```
$sess = New-PSSession $SETTING_SESSION_HOST

$wml = Invoke-Command -Session $sess -ScriptBlock {Get-VM | where State -eq 'Running'}

$wml.Name
```

PS: while writing this i noticed you set `$wml` to `Receive-Job $job` but then you iterate through `$vml` so it might just be a typo `v` for `w`

Comment: the problem I found is that when there are more than 1 machine running, the return is Object[], and I need a different way of handling this.